# Xcode refusing to install app onto iPhone

Tags: ios, xcode, installation

I have Mountain Lion running Xcode 4.4.1 and an iPhone project. I can run it in the simulator.  It also builds for the phone, but it refuses to run on the phone. On run, it immediately reports:

```
error: failed to launch '/Users/ion/Library/Developer/Xcode/
DerivedData/Proj-demgmyrpwcixoufcnwxoupxmksey/Build/Products/
Debug-iphoneos/Proj.app/Proj' -- No such file or directory
(/Users/ion/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Proj-
demgmyrpwcixoufcnwxoupxmksey/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Proj.app/Proj)
```

There has been much discussion on the web and here about clearing DerivedData, rebooting the phone and computer, but none of it has helped for me.

The one thing I have noticed is that, although I am trying to run it on an iPhone 4S, it is trying to launch from my computer's filesystem. Shouldn't it says "/var/mobile/..." instead?

This is grinding my development to a complete halt.

My suspicion is that it is failing to install the app onto the phone or that it is mixing up the phone and computer paths.

Does anyone have any ideas on how I might diagnose or otherwise get more detailed information on what Xcode is doing when I try to run it on the phone?

Comment: You are signing this thing correctly, yes?

Comment: Does the "missing" file actually exist? Also, check whether there are any spaces in the project name or any directory names; sometimes Xcode doesn't escape or quote paths properly.

Comment: I had a similar problem and went through all the discussions about deleting DerivedData, etc. that you have found.  Turned out to be a code signing issue, so triple check that all your signing is in order, as CodaFi alluded to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FYI, I did solve this in the end. The problem turned out to be a typo in one of the capabilities lists in the Info.plist file. Surely, this must be one of the most misleading error descriptions ever.